# Some characters (trademark sign, etc) unable to write to a file but is printable on the screen

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, unicode-string

I've been trying to scrape data from a website and write out the data that I find to a file. More than 90% of the time, I don't run into Unicode errors but when the data has the following characters such as "Burger King®, Hans Café", it doesn't like writing that into the file so my error handling prints it to the screen as is and without any further errors.

I've tried the encode and decode functions and the various encodings but to no avail.

Please find an excerpt of the current code that I've written below:

```
import urllib2,sys
import re
import os
import urllib
import string
import time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString, SoupStrainer
from string import maketrans
import codecs

f=codecs.open('alldetails7.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
...


soup5 = BeautifulSoup(html5)
enc_s5 = soup5.originalEncoding

for company in iter(soup5.findAll(height="20px")):
    stream = ""
    count_detail = 1
    for tag in iter(company.findAll('td')):
        if count_detail > 1:
           stream = stream + tag.text.replace(u',',u';')
           if count_detail < 4 :
              stream=stream+","
        count_detail = count_detail + 1
    stream.strip()
    try:
        f.write(str(stnum)+","+br_name_addr+","+stream.decode(enc_s5)+os.linesep)
    except:
        print "Unicode error ->"+str(storenum)+","+branch_name_address+","+stream
```

Comment: What's the actual exception message .. should be useful. You call `decode()` on stream, i.e. you expect `stream` to be non-unicode string encoded in `enc_s5` - is that really true? Maybe it is already unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `f.write()` line doesn't make sense to me - `stream` will be a `unicode` since it's made indirectly from from `tag.text` and [BeautifulSoup gives you Unicode](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit), so you shouldn't call `decode` on `stream`.  (You use `decode` to turn a `str` with a particular character encoding into a `unicode`.)  You've opened the file for writing with `codecs.open()` and told it to use UTF-8, so you can just `write()` a `unicode` and that should work.  So, instead I would try:

```
f.write(unicode(stnum)+br_name_addr+u","+stream+os.linesep)
```

... or, supposing that instead you had just opened the file with `f=open('alldetails7.txt','w')`, you would do:

```
line = unicode(stnum)+br_name_addr+u","+stream+os.linesep
f.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks..your answer knocked some sense into me with regards to Unicode. This stuff was killing me and your input led me to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the encoding of the file you're writing to, and made sure the characters can be shown in the encoding you're trying to write to the file? Try setting the character encoding to UTF-8 or something else explicitly to have the characters show up.

Comment: Thanks for the input... this led me to look for the particular encoding that I needed which is latin-1.